# How to deploy MASTER/BACKUP machines using Puppet?

Tags: puppet, keep-alive, tcp-keepalive

I have 2 VMs.
I'm using keepalived to have them as MASTER/BACKUP with the same VIP. (http://www.keepalived.org)
I want to deploy the machines one by one using Puppet.

I want to deploy the the BACKUP first and when it finishes, deploy the MASTER.

What is the best way to do it using Puppet?

Comment: I believe you can use subscribe for achieving this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20325371/puppet-relationship-between-resources-on-different-nodes. The upshot is that Puppet doesn't do orchestration between nodes :-(